# в многомерный массив динамически добавить ли удалить элемент

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив с данными:

```
$arrayData =
    [
        'one' =>
            [
                'two' => 1,
                'three' =>
                    [
                        'four' => 1,
                    ],
            ],
    ];
```

и массив, данные из которого нужно добавить в $arrayData:

```
$arrayAdd =
    [
        'one' =>
            [
                'two' =>
                    [
                        'data'   => 1, //значение (прибавить, отнять или на него заменить), которое нужно изменить в $arrayData['one']['one']
                        'action' => 'increment',  //варианты: increment / decrement / replace (если decrement и значения нет - 0)
                    ],
            ],
    ];
```

в результате получить:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [two] => 2
            [three] => Array
                (
                    [four] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

как это можно сделать?

Comment: добавлять и удалять элементы в массиве можно как обычно, написав обычный код удаление и добавления элементов массива

Comment: $arrayAdd формируется скриптом и добавить нужно програмно в массив $arrayData, в этом и проблема, по сути речь идёт о array_merge_recursive только значение нужно менять по условию, а не просто сливать ключи

Comment: ну так пройдитесь циклом по массивам, найдите места, которые нужно менять, через `if` и меняйте, а потом вставляйте правильные данные

Comment: получается в рекурсии $arrayAdd собрать ключи и потом вызвать рекурсию $arrayData массива и в нём найти эти ключи?

Answer (score 0):

Если прямо вот под указанный пример, то как-то так:

```php
<?php
$arrayData = [ 'one' => [ 'two' => 1, 'three' => [ 'four' => 1, ], ], ];
$arrayAdd = [ 'one' => [ 'two' => [
                        'data'   => 1, 
                        'action' => 'increment', 
                    ],
            ],
    ];


foreach( $arrayData as $key => $value ) {
    //$key == "one" exist this $key in $arrayAdd ?
    if ( isset( $arrayAdd[$key] ) && is_array( $arrayAdd[$key] ) && count( $arrayAdd[$key] ) > 0 ) {
        //yes, exist
        foreach( $value as $k => $v ) {
            //$k == "two", "three", exist this key ($k) in $arrayAdd[$key][] ?
            if ( !is_null($k) && is_numeric( $v ) && isset( $arrayAdd[$key][$k] ) && is_array( $arrayAdd[$key][$k] ) && 
                 isset( $arrayAdd[$key][$k]['data'] ) && is_numeric($arrayAdd[$key][$k]['data']) && 
                 isset($arrayAdd[$key][$k]['action']) && 
                 in_array(mb_convert_case($arrayAdd[$key][$k]['action'], MB_CASE_LOWER), ['increment', 'decrement', 'replace']) ) {
                 $tmpValue = $arrayData[$key][$k];
                 if (  mb_convert_case($arrayAdd[$key][$k]['action'], MB_CASE_LOWER) == 'increment' ) {
                     $tmpValue = $tmpValue + $arrayAdd[$key][$k]['data'];
                 } elseif (  mb_convert_case($arrayAdd[$key][$k]['action'], MB_CASE_LOWER) == 'decrement' ) {
                     $tmpValue = $tmpValue - $arrayAdd[$key][$k]['data'];
                 } else {
                     $tmpValue = $arrayAdd[$key][$k]['data'];
                 }
                $arrayData[$key][$k] = $tmpValue;
            } 
        }
    }   
}
print_r( $arrayData );
```

Результат:

```
Array ( [one] => Array( [two] => 2, 
                        [three] => Array( [four] => 1 ) 
                       ) 
       )
```